# Redirect Standard Output to List<string> or Stream

Tags: c#, unit-testing, output

I'm writing test code for the following method:

```
public static void PrintAll<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection)
{
    foreach (T item in collection)
    {
        Console.Write(item.ToString());
    }
}
```

So essentially what I think needs to be done is that I can fill an array with random data, output it using this method, store it in a stream/collection and then output it using the standard foreach loop and compare the two.

I understand that `Console.Write()` doesn't actually write to the console it writes to my application's standard output.

I know how to redirect this for other `Process` objects but have no clue how to redirect my own application's standard output, any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Console.SetOut](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setout(v=vs.110).aspx) to set the output of the console temporarily to a string.

For example:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb);
// Save the standard output.
TextWriter tmp = Console.Out;
Console.SetOut(sw);
// Code which calls Console.Write
Console.SetOut(tmp);
string actual = sb.ToString();
```

Remember to dispose the `StringWriter` object.